# How should i design a wordpress backend + react + java frontend app?

Tags: java, node.js, wordpress, express, reactjs

For about 2 weeks, i'm trying to design a system, should consider below requires;

- We have already an frontend app, has been written in java (we don't want to change it)
- we want to make our backend system with wordpress
- our UI team will design ui in react
- I should consider SEO and other standard web requirements

**1st design:**

I will get rests from WP-backend (or directly from database) and with java build-in time js, I will compile react in my app

**2nd Design:**

Java will make a request to nodejs (working in :3000) with datas from wp-backend (or database) and node with express + react will render an html and give output. Java will take this output and place it in view side.

**3rd Design ?**

I couldn't find the best way of this job. Can someone help me to find best design with some explanations ?

Best,

Comment: Personally I don't like wordpress backend. Why don't you use java in your backend? Any reason?

Comment: @SaiYeYanNaingAye Yes, our customer already has some experiences with wordpress, and they resist on it.

Comment: Java at frontend or Javascript?

Answer (score 3):

1) From what I can understand your client likes and insist of using the WordPress dashboard as an interface.
How do you achieve this? simple just install WordPress somewhere where, give access to your client to that WordPress instance admin and let him have fun adding data.

2) Get data saved by the client
2.a) Build your solution that will get data from the database, manipulate it as you want and send it to any front end engine/setup that you want. WordPress database is pretty easy to understand ( it has quite some documentation including diagrams and the number of tables is pretty small ) so I'm pretty sure you can come up with a setup that will work.
2.b) Create a front end client that will make api calls to the WordPress instance - here are a few things that are built in WordPress that you can call using your client: [built in endpoints](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_APIs) and there is also a [WP API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/) plugin that helps you with this. Both WordPress and the plugin can be extended with your own custom things if need though you probably want to use as much as you can from the.

2.c) Create a ReactJS powered WordPress theme - there are multiple ways of setting this up that depend on your use case but making ajax calls to WordPress backend is pretty straight forward so you can load whatever resources you want in different views/states/whatever of your front end app.

From your question I don't get why you need to go throw so many things:
Make a call to WordPress functions to get data using a java app that then will make a call to a nodejs app that will render a view that gets back to the java app that then will display the info? this just sounds wrong...

Either get the data from the WordPress database using the java app and send the info to the reactjs front end.

Or just skip the java app and get the data to the front end using ajax calls against the wordpress api/ajax api.

I might be missing some of your needs but try to keep the stack as simple as possible.

Comment: Our frontend app already has been developer in JAVA and we don't want to change it (but only a few changes). We don't need react powered wordpress app, i need react powered java app. but with only react there will be "seo" problems, so i want to make my system based on server-side rendering.

And soo..?

Comment: then probably you should go with point 2.a but the more you complicate things the more you go to a greyish solution that will be hard to maintain hard to scale and hard to explain it to the customer or other developers ( audits and things ). Again you should be able to craft your solution with the info above. Best luck.

Comment: Just hit a post that links to data that might help you: https://pantheon.io/decoupled-cms